# Detect window resize to run different attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I am looking to change the parameters of bxslider, depending on the viewport size. However, I would like this to work if the user resizes their browser (Or rotate their mobile device). So far I have the following code below which runs the relevant function. However, this doesn't detect the re-size? How do I detect for this? In addition, I have certain way I run the functions I use (Only if an element exists on the page etc, so between the comments is where I require my code.)

```
    clientsSlider: function () {
        if ($('.clients').length ) {


            //  

            if($(window).width() >= 1024){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                  minSlides: 4,
                  maxSlides: 4,
                  slideWidth: 170,
                  slideMargin:100,
                  responsive: true
                });  
            }

            if($(window).width() <= 1024){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                  minSlides: 2,
                  maxSlides: 2,
                  slideWidth: 170,
                  slideMargin:50,
                  responsive: true
                });  
            }

            //                                      
        }   
    }
```

Comment: bxSlider has responsive behavior built in. You shouldn't be re-initializing it manually.

Comment: ... or you should be using `reloadSlider()`. http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) method to detect resizing of the window:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 1024){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 4,
          maxSlides: 4,
          slideWidth: 170,
          slideMargin:100,
          responsive: true
        });  
    } else {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 2,
          maxSlides: 2,
          slideWidth: 170,
          slideMargin:50,
          responsive: true
        });  
    }
});
```

*BTW you shouldn't be using >= and <= 1024 in your if statements as both will execute if the width is 1024px. The else in my code above is sufficient*